# Javascript image width is 0 on load

Tags: javascript, image, loading

I have this code for loading several images:

```
    const imageURLS = ["lvls/1.png", "assets/tileatlas.png"];
let imageCount = imageURLS.length;
let assets = [];

function imageLoaded(i){
    imageCount--;
    if(imageCount == 0){
        window.TILEATLAS = assets[0];

        load();
    }
}

function loadAssets(){
    for(let i = 0, len = imageCount; i < len; i++){

        let image = new Image();

        image.src = imageURLS[i];
        assets.push(image);

        image.onload = imageLoaded(image);
    }
}

onload = loadAssets();
```

but when I try to access the images in the load() functions, it says the width and height are 0, for me indicating the images aren't finished loading, but they should be? I'm dumbfounded...

Comment: `image.onload = () => imageLoaded(image)`

Comment: Worked perfectly, but why does this work and my code doesn't?

Comment: When you do `imageLoaded(image)` you immidiately execute the function.
Therefore `onload` ends up being the result of `imageLoaded(image)`, not the function itself.
`const myFunction = otherFunction` vs `const myFunction = otherFunction()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
image.onload = imageLoaded(image);
```

Because you have the parenthesis, Javascript calls the function immediately and expects it to return the result that will be passed to the `onload`
You need something like this:

```
const imageURLS = ["lvls/1.png", "assets/tileatlas.png"];
let imageCount = imageURLS.length;
let assets = [];

function imageLoaded(){
    var i = this
    imageCount--;
    if(imageCount == 0){
        window.TILEATLAS = assets[0];

        load();
    }
}

function loadAssets(){
    for(let i = 0, len = imageCount; i < len; i++){

        let image = new Image();

        image.src = imageURLS[i];
        assets.push(image);

        image.onload = imageLoaded.bind(image);
    }
}

onload = loadAssets();
```

The `bind` function sets the value of `this` in the function to the argument. This way, it won't call the function, but create it.

Comment: what is this mystery `i` here `    `i = this` - not a good thing to create a global variable like that; and then never use it

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I assumed he needed the variable `i`, as it is the argument in the original function. However, with the `bind` function, it sets the value to `this`, not `i`. I used the `i = this` to prevent errors in the code if he ever used the variable `i` without changing it to `this`. I just forgot to add the `var` before it, I will change it.

Comment: oh yeah sorry for the i thingy, I literally mistyped that lmao, reall don't know how that ended up here, but good to know for later!